# How to remove this?

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

Am using the flash player, when i right click on it, its showing like this
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8a4fbddec9.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8a4fbddec9.png)

How i can remove MediaXxxScript.com when i rightclick on the player?

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this is done through the context menu `flash.ui.ContextMenu` by adding context menu items `flash.ui.ContextMenuItem` The class you are using would be adding these, so you can either find where that happens and remove it or add something like this after that meny is created to override it

```
    var _menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    _menu.hideBuiltInItems();
    this.contextMenu = _menu;
```

Comment: where i can fing flash.ui.ContextMenu?

Comment: thanks for suggestion, can u please tell me where can i found flash.ui.ContextMenuItem

Comment: it's a standard library in AS3. you can find more info here
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html